# How to remove NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval entirely

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I wave a time value inside `NSUserDefaults` , and when I'm reusing my `ViewController` my `NSTimer` adds +1 to Interval

here my update function:

```
func fireUpdatedLimit() {
        var endTimeSeconds = userDefaults.integerForKey("endTimeSeconds\(currentUserId!)")
        if endTimeSeconds > 0  {
            endTimeSeconds += 1
            userDefaults.setInteger(endTimeSeconds, forKey: "endTimeSeconds\(currentUserId!)")
        }
        self.timer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateLimit), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

and here what I've already tried:

```
weak var timer = NSTimer() 
weak var timer: NSTimer?

self.timer = nil 
self.timer.invalidate()
```

logic:

```
func updateLimit() {

        var timeLeft = userDefaults.integerForKey("endTimeSeconds\(currentUserId!)")
        foregroundAction() {
            self.lockedTimeLabel.hidden = false
            self.lockedImageView.hidden = false
        }
        self.lockedTimeLabel.text = String(fromTimeInterval: Double(timeLeft))
        if timeLeft <= 0 {
            print("ended")
            foregroundAction() {
                self.lockedImageView.hidden = true
                self.lockedTimeLabel.hidden = true
                self.mediaImageView.hidden = true
                self.followerImageView.hidden = true
            }
            self.reloadContent()
            userDefaults.setInteger(timeLeft, forKey: "endTimeSeconds\(currentUserId!)")
            self.timer!.invalidate()
        } else {
            timeLeft -= 1

            userDefaults.setInteger(timeLeft, forKey: "endTimeSeconds\(currentUserId!)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you invalidate the timer? In which function?  `viewWillDisappear` is probably a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the timer to `nil` then the reference is broken and you can't invalidate it, so you must call `invalidate` first.

Ensure that you always check the reference and invalidate when you're going to create a new timer as that also breaks any reference to the old timer.

Also, never create a dummy / placeholder timer with `Timer()`, you require an optional reference (`?`).

Comment: yo, I know it, I've tried different combinations invalidation and setting it to nil

Comment: Do both, invalidate and then set to nil

Comment: still have dat bug

Comment: What bug, you asked (kind of) about cleaning up, what is actually wrong?

Comment: so when I'm moving from 1ViewController to 2ViewController and than back 
fireUpdatedLimit() is called with that should decrement timer by 1, bug it decrementing by 2 instead, later  moving from 1ViewController to 2ViewController  causes N - 1 decrement

Comment: Do you mean increment as you show no code to decrement? What calls fireUpdateLimit!

Comment: fireUpdateLimit! is called by viewDidLoad()

Comment: So what does the timer have to do with this? Your problem really isn't described well as it seems now that you have a logical variable management issue rather than any problem with a timer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112449/discussion-between-wain-and--).